# Salesforce Lightning Locker Service / Aura Component Range Inconsistencies

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, javascript, locker-service

In my Salesforce Lightning Locker Service / Aura Component application there seems to be 2 representations for range objects:

Type 1.

- prints to console as `Proxy {}`
- does not implement `range.isPointInRange`
- implements `range.toString`

Type 2.

- prints to console as `n {}`
- implements `range.isPointInRange`
- does not implement `range.toString` (returns `[object Object]`)
- `document.createRange` mostly creates this kind of range for me, after a while they seem to turn into Type 1 ranges somehow.

It's unclear to me the mechanism for how "Type 2" ranges turn into "Type 1", and what triggers it.

I am interested in using both `isPointInRange` and `toString` in my app.

One workaround is to create a "Type 2" range every time I need `isPointInRange`. However, I also need to know the circumstances in which a "Type 1" range is created to use `toString`.

---

Edit: this question is a distilled version of some issues posted here: [Salesforce Lightning Component Range Object compatibility issues](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382551/salesforce-lightning-component-range-object-compatibility-issues)
.

Comment: Sorry, I have difficulties to conceive your setup. Could you provide relevant snippets from your code? E.g. how do you know you still have a range object looking at the variable holding "Type 1"? What do you mean by "prints to console"? Any idea what "n {}" is? Do you use a single Aura component, or is this in a component hierarchy? Do you source the Javascript from a static resource / ltng:require?

Comment: Hi Felix, there is some sample code here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382551/salesforce-lightning-component-range-object-compatibility-issues

The Type 2 range is created with `document.createRange()`. It's cached in a dictionary for reference and at some point (which I cannot reproduce intentionally)  it turns into a Type 1 range. 

When I say "prints to console as" I mean `x = document.createRange(); console.log(x)`. No idea what "n {}" is. The code is in a single Aura component, that imports a static JavaScript resource.