# Locker Service SecureWindow returning undefined nodes in Selection API

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, locker-service

I'm building an LWC with a dependency on the Selection API.

Nodes referenced in Selection or Ranges (i.e. window.getSelection()) behave as expected except where a node in the range or selection is a text node. I'm thinking this is a Locker Service bug, where text nodes within an LWC are treated as though they're shared/insecure and cannot be accessed (though I think they should be).

For instance, when the caret lies within a text node (within the LWC), calls via locker service return undefined for the anchor/extent nodes and so on, see below:

[image: SecureWindow vs window]

If however the caret lies within any other type of node (i.e. in a span) it behaves as expected (in this case the anchors are proxied - but all are correct):

[image: Selection of any node]

To demonstrate more clearly, if I have the HTML as follows:

[image: HTML Selection]

And I select the span as well as the spaces (text node) in the browser like so:

[image: Rendered Selection]

We see that the end of the selection behaves correctly (I selected from right to left) but the end/focus does not (both should be the text node).

[image: Selection over Text and Span]

All these examples have a single range, if we query the range in the selection all references where a text node is expected are also undefined.

Interestingly none of the above weirdness happens when I run the same LWC via an sfdx local development server, maybe locker service isn't invoked locally, but can't help but think I may be missing something?

Checked into getting the selection via the shadow root (i.e. this.template.getSelection()) but this looks like it's not supported yet by locker. Any help?

Comment: Is [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/382551/salesforce-lightning-component-range-object-compatibility-issues) possibly interesting in your context?

Answer (score 0):

This has started working now, SecureWindow no longer returns undefined for text nodes.

[image: textNode working]